# What C++ library can I use to check disk quotas on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, quota

Is there an easy to use library that I can use for checking disk quotas? I need to modify a piece of software I have to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just use `quotactl`?

```
int quotactl(int cmd, const char *special, int id, caddr_t addr);
```

Comment: I included quota.h but I get this error "/usr/include/linux/quota.h:175:15: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘caddr_t’

Do I need to include anything else?

Comment: @gbu: What is that line (on your system, because things move around depending on kernel version)?

Comment: According to the manpage for `quotactl`, you have to include `<sys/types.h>` before `<sys/quota.h>`.

Comment: I'm looking at the documentation here - http://landru.uwaterloo.ca/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=2&topic=quotactl and it looks like this function is to set quotas. I only want to check the quota limit.

Comment: It's supposed to be the block device, e.g. "/dev/sda1"

Comment: @Erik: I set the block device but it says Invalid argument. Am I supposed to set addr to something?

Comment: @gbu: Yes, as specified in `man quotactl` you need to pass the address of a `struct dqblk` for the Q_GETQUOTA subcommand.

Comment: @Erik: I'm looking at struct dqblk in quota.h but I don't undertand how to use it. The struct has variables like dqb_bhardlimit, dqb_bsoftlimit, etc but how am I supposed to know what to set for those variables?

Comment: @gbu: You don't set them, you pass such a struct to quotactl and then afterwards you *read* them

Comment: Hm, that's what I tried -    const char *d = "/dev/sdb9";
   dqblk *addr;
   int r = quotactl(Q_GETQUOTA, d, 500, addr);


but I get this error - cannot convert ‘dqblk*’ to ‘char*’ for argument ‘4’ to ‘int quotactl(int, const char*, int, char*)’

Comment: `dqblk blk; quotactl(QCMD(Q_GETQUOTA, USRQUOTA), "/dev/sdb9", 500, (char *) &blk);`